# generated Set_model path in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I'm used scaffold_controller to generate a controller for a model I have.  In my view, I have the following link to

```
link_to, 'Like', like_path(param: 'param')
```

In my controller that was generated, I have a private method set_like which is called and I can figure out why.  I just want the link to go to the likes#new path, but it's going to the set_like method first.   I feel like this is a new rails thing and I'm not sure why.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use "new_like_path" rather than "like_path".

You probably would benefit from reading this closely: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

When you use "like_path" you are linking to an existing record, whose id you should pass to the "like_path" route generator. Like:

```
like_path(2)  # link to like with id==2
```